# Quiero saber con una consulta sql me muestre cual de todos los campos de una tabla es llave foranea

Tags: java, html, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

necesito una consulta sql que me muestra uno o todos los campos de una tabla que son llave foranea preferiblemente que funcione con mysql ya intente con esto   `SELECT *FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE TABLE_NAME  = 'NombreTabla'`
y no funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT table_name,
       column_name,
       constraint_name,
       referenced_table_name,
       referenced_column_name
FROM   information_schema.key_column_usage
WHERE  referenced_table_name = 'tablaNombre';
```

Por ejemplo con la database de ejemplo Sakila de MySQL:

```sql
SELECT table_name,
       column_name,
       constraint_name,
       referenced_table_name,
       referenced_column_name
FROM   information_schema.key_column_usage
WHERE  referenced_table_name = 'actor';
```

Resultado:

```sql
+------------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | CONSTRAINT_NAME     | REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME | REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME | 
+------------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| film_actor | actor_id    | fk_film_actor_actor | actor                 | actor_id               |
+------------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

> Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/xxx5Hs3m

Saludos ✌